# Which of the following options are correct with respect to a MST?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm taking the [Algorithms: Design and Analysis II](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms2+SelfPaced/about) course, and one of the questions is as follows:

> Consider a connected undirected graph with distinct edge costs. Which
>   of the following are true? [Check all that apply.]
>
> 1. Suppose the edge  is not the cheapest edge that crosses the cut (,). Then  does not belong to any minimum spanning tree.
> 2. Suppose the edge  is the most expensive edge contained in the cycle . Then  does not belong to any minimum spanning tree.
> 3. The minimum spanning tree is unique.
> 4. Suppose the edge  is the cheapest edge that crosses the cut (,). Then  belongs to every minimum spanning tree.

To my knowledge, all four options are correct. Options 1, 2 and 4 follow from the Cut property; option 3 is correct because edge weights are distinct. However, including option 1 is turning out to be wrong. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. No
> 2. Yes
> 3. Yes
> 4. Yes

The main part here is to answer #3. [For a graph with all distinct edge costs that is true.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352163/show-that-theres-a-unique-minimum-spanning-tree-if-all-edges-have-different-cos) Answers for all other questions you can derive using answer to the third one.

For #1:

```
 A1 --- B1
        |
 A2 --- B2
```

Suppose `w(A1,B1) > w(A2,B2)`, but you still need to include both of them into MST.

Comment: What would be the cut in your example?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar one part is `A1`, `A2` and second part is `B1`, `B2`. It is also OK to have edge which connects `A1` and `A2`, but with big enough weight. Imagine a cycle with a cut which not includes the most expensive edge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets look at the mst definition.MST is a subset of a connected undirected graph with distinct edge costs that connects all the vertices together, without any cycles and with the minimum possible total edge weight.

1.If the edge e is  the only way to traverse A to B without causing a cycle it may belong to a mst.

2.If there is a cycle C then we can't talk about mst it will be a closed path.That is the definition of the cycle.

3.If each edge has a distinct cost as you mentioned then there will be only one, unique minimum spanning tree.

4.It may not because it can cause a loop like cycle or circuit then we don't use that edge to traverse A to B